# On Chebyshev’s Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Chebyshev’s Inequality is:
[image: Generalized Chebyshev’s Inequality]

If $b_{1} \leq b_{2} \leq b_{3} \leq ... \leq b_{n}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i m_i \leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i m_i\right)$.
And the proof is as follows:
[image]

I want to know, when $b_{1} \leq b_{2} \leq b_{3} \leq ... \leq b_{n}$, could we get a constant $C_{ab} \leq 1$, such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i m_i \leq C_{ab} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i m_i\right). $$

More specifically, when $a_{i} = \lambda_{i}$, $b_{i} = (1-\lambda_{i})^{2}$ with $\lambda_{i} < 1$, could we get a constant $C_{ab}$ that is strictly less than 1($C_{ab} < 1$)?

And if we don't have the condition $\lambda_{i} < 1$, what results could we get?

Does anybody knows?